# JavaScript garbage collection in a closure

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I'm using closures in my game engine for objects. Say something like:

```
var newSprite = function() {
   var x = 0;
   var y = 0;
   var returnobj = {
       getPos:function(){
          return [x,y];
       }
   }
   return returnobj;
}
```

That's not the actual code but it illustrates well. I have the objects in a scenegraph, if I set the objects in the scenegraph to null, will the garbage collection collect all this right? Will I have to set each variable to null?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you clarified what "the objects in a scenegraph" means, preferably with code. Similarly what you mean by "set each variable to null."

Comment: When each object is made it's added to an array to draw to canvas. When I say "set each variable to null" I mean; scenegraph[3]=null

Answer (score 5):

It will, unless:

1. Somebody else is holding on to a reference to a given sprite.
2. Somebody else is holding on to a reference to the `someSprite.getPos` method.

Example:

```
var sceneGraph = [newSprite(), newSprite(), newSprite()];
var gotYourSprite = sceneGraph[0];
var gotYourMethod = gotYourSprite.getPos;

sceneGraph = null;
// gotYourSprite is still available and is not GC'ed, but the other two are gone.
gotYourSprite = null;
// gotYourSprite is gone, but neither the method nor the private variables can be
// GC'ed because you still have gotYourMethod, which captured x and y.
gotYourMethod = null;
// Now everything will be GC'ed.
```

Comment: and those other references are reachable.

Comment: what if I set the returnobj, that's returned to everything, itself to null?

Comment: Can you give some sample code of what that would look like? Remember that `returnobj` is just a reference to the in-memory structure; if someone else has a reference to the structure that sometimes goes by the name `returnobj` and sometimes by the name `myOtherReferenceToTheSprite`, then setting `returnobj` to `null` will not do anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Once your object is null, the references in the closure are no longer reachable and will be garbage collected.  Provided nothing else has a reference to things inside that object.